# Looping over undefined array keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

## Problem:

I have a DB containing math exercises, split by difficulty levels and date taken.

i want to generate a diagram of the performance over time.

to achieve this, i loop through the query results, and `++` a counter for the level and day the exercise was taken.

example: level 2 exercise was taken at 01.11.2015.
`this.levels[2].daysAgo[1].amountTaken++;`

with this, i can build a diagram, where day 0 is always today, and the performance over days is shown.

now levels[] has a predefined amount of levels, so there is no problem with that.
but daysAgo[] is very dynamic (it even changes daily with the same data), so if there was only one exercise taken, it would wander on a daily basis (from `daysAgo[0]` to `daysAgo[1]` and so on).
the `daysAgo[]` between that would be empty (because there are no entries).

but for evaluating the diagram, i need them to have an initialized state with `amountTaken: 0,` and so on.

problem being: i can't know when the oldest exercise was.

## Idea 1:

First gather all entries in a kind of proxy object, where i have a `var maxDaysAgo` that holds the value for the oldest exercise, then initialize an array `daysAgo[maxDaysAgo]` that gets filled with 0-entries, before inserting the actual entries.

that seems very clumsy and overly complicated

## Idea 2:

Just add the entries `this.level[level].daysAgo[daysAgo].amountTaken++;`, possibly leaving the `daysAgo` array with a lot of `undefined` keys.
Then, after all entries are added, i would loop over the `daysAgo`keys with

```
for (var i = 1; i < this.maxLevel; i++) {                       // for every level
  for (var j = 0; j < this.levels[i].daysAgo.length; j++) {
```

but `daysAgo.length`will not count undefined fields, will it?

So if i have one single entry at [24], `length` will still be 1 :/

## Question:

How can I find out the highest key in an array and loop until there, when there are undefined keys between?
How can i adress all undefined keys up until the highest (and not any more)?

Or: what would be a different, more elegant way to solve this whole problem altogether?

Thanks :)

Comment: amount of records is also totally unpredictable. could be 1, could be 10000000

Comment: "_but `daysAgo.length` will not count `undefined` fields, will it?_" Just give it a try... `var foo = []; foo[4] = 1; console.log(foo.length)` will show what? [MDN/Array: Relationship between length and numerical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) returns one higher than the highest numerical index, so can be used to loop though even undefined values

as a test:

```
var a=[]
a[24]=1
console.log(a.length)
```

outputs 25 for me (in chrome and firefox).

Comment: now THIS solves my problem (if it works in node, which i suppose) :)
i was thinking it would actually COUNT the amount of indexes, skipping un-enumerable/undefined etc

Comment: should do, node uses v8 which is the same JS engine used by chrome